# Travel API doesn't work for cities outside of the US - why?

Tags: api, sabre

I have been trying out the travel API from sabre, been testing APIs (for example InstaFlights Search or destination finder) and it works only for US cities (departure and destination). I've been testing them on sabres website (so this has nothing to do with my code). I don't assume that sabre API is only for US domestic flights as that would be too strange, so does anyone know why I'm getting 404 when I try to put a non-US city as departure or destination?
Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Random international flights options do work and some don't. 
For example MUC-LHR ( Munich to London) works when I change the point of sale country to DE but doesn't work for MUC - JFK for example.

Answer (score 1):

Are you hitting  CERT or PROD? Not all of Sabre content is available in CERT, so that might be why you're seeing such odd results.

Comment: I am only trying out there API Explorer (https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs) where you fill in the values and send the request and when I was writing my own get requests, I was sending them to their test environment (https://api.test.sabre.com)

Comment: the API explorer works of a CERT Sandbox, so yes, content and destinations are limited. Make sure to also look at changing the point of sale country (pointofsalecountry).  https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/instaflights_search#usage_notes

Comment: The instaflights api may also be more limited than the bfm api? I know it pulls from different sources...